# Find next available date from a person

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

So imagine a person has a daily schedule. Each day he has a time range in which he will be available.

```
{
    "_id": "ObjectId("5570ff8dc7234868035138c9")",
    "name": "John Doe",
    "schedule": [
        {
            "day": 1, // monday
            "from_hour": 10, // time range
            "from_minute": 30,
            "to_hour": 11,
            "to_minute": 0
        },
        {
            "day": 2, // tuesday
            "from_hour": 9, // time range
            "from_minute": 0,
            "to_hour": 12,
            "to_minute": 0
        },
        {
            "day": 5, // friday
            "from_hour": 10, // time range
            "from_minute": 30,
            "to_hour": 11,
            "to_minute": 0
        }
    ]
}
```

User can add an appointment with the person at an available date. The appointment will look like this.

```
{
    "_id": "ObjectId("5570ff8dc7234868035138c9")",
    "from_time": "2015-07-15T03:30:00.000Z", // UTC time for Monday, 15-6-2015 10:30
    "to_time": "2015-07-15T04:00:00.000Z" // UTC time for Monday, 15-6-2015 11:00
}
```

Now, suppose there is another person who wants to find a person's available time slot after a particular date. How can this query be done? I've been thinking of various ways but no results. Please help.

**EDIT** if anyone has a better schema than this, I'm all ears. This one is all I could think of. Thanks.

Comment: here is problem with `schedule` array, is any options available to find out which `year,month` appointment should place ?

Comment: Is the appointment an embedded document or a separate collection?

Comment: @yogesh: appointment can be created as long as a person has a schedule on that day, hour, and minute

Comment: @chridam: appointment is a separate collection

Comment: I don't understand why you use a proper date type in your "appointment", but not for the "person" ? That would help to find the _minimum greater than something ..._

Comment: @SylvainLeroux: because a person's schedule is not based on a timestamp, it's a daily basis, i.e. I have schedule every monday at 12:00 until 13:00

Comment: which relation maintain to find out in both collections ?

Comment: @yogesh: "which relation maintain to find out in both collections" I don't quite understand what that means

Comment: @Zycoo I could understand that, but if you only store the "usual weekly schedule" of a person, how would record a fact like _"next Friday I have an appointment from 12:30 to 14:00 ?"_ That does not mean that _every_ Friday I'm booked. And what about holidays ?

Comment: @SylvainLeroux then I would query all appointments that are in next Friday's date, no?